# React-Router-Dom V6 Vs V5

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, cdn

Trying to create a minimalist React Application using CDN to test React-router-dom. The below code works fine:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>


    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.3.4/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
 
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
      const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
      const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;

        function App(){

        return (

        <Router>
          <nav>
        <br/><Link to="/">TO HOME</Link>
        <br/><Link to="/a">TO A</Link>
        <br/><Link to="/b">TO B</Link>
          </nav>

          <Route path="/" exact component={()=><h1>Home</h1>} />
      <Route path="/a" component={()=><h1>A</h1>} />
          <Route path="/b" component={()=><h1>B</h1>} />
         < / Router>
        );}

    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(<App />);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I switch to the latest version of react-router-dom 6.17.0

```html
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.17.0/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I get an error:

```
index.tsx:1858 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Route')
    at Object.get [as Route] (index.tsx:1858:1)
    at <anonymous>:4:28
```

Also, I am checking the exports in the CDN link and I don't see Route being exported, while it is in the earlier version. Should this be done differently in version 6.17 of react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure *why*, but adding other various "missing dependencies" appears to get the React-Router v6 code working for the use case.

- `react-router@6.18.0`: https://unpkg.com/react-router@6.18.0/dist/umd/react-router.development.js
- `@remix/router@1.11.0`: https://unpkg.com/@remix-run/router@1.11.0/dist/router.umd.min.js

The `Route` component is able to be imported now. Also import the `Routes` component as it replaced the React-Router v5 `Switch` component and handles route matching/rendering. `Route` directly wraps a group of `Route` components.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@remix-run/router@1.11.0/dist/router.umd.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@6.18.0/dist/umd/react-router.development.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.18.0/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
 
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
      const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
      const Routes = ReactRouterDOM.Routes;
      const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;

      function App() {
        return (
          <Router>
            <nav>
              <br/><Link to="/">TO HOME</Link>
              <br/><Link to="/a">TO A</Link>
              <br/><Link to="/b">TO B</Link>
            </nav>

            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
              <Route path="/a" element={<h1>A</h1>} />
              <Route path="/b" element={<h1>B</h1>} />
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        );
      }

      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
      root.render(<App />);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the BrowserRouter, Link, and Route elements from react-router-dom and use them in the code accordingly.

The Route component from version 5 is now replaced with the Route element in version 6.

```
...
<script>
      const { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } = ReactRouterDOM;

      function App() {
        return (
          <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <nav>
                <br/><Link to="/">TO HOME</Link>
                <br/><Link to="/a">TO A</Link>
                <br/><Link to="/b">TO B</Link>
              </nav>

              <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
              <Route path="/a" element={<h1>A</h1>} />
              <Route path="/b" element={<h1>B</h1>} />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </div>
        );
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
</script>
...
```

Comment: Still getting the same error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Route'). if you open the CDN in the browser the "Route" is just not being exported.

Comment: try to use this CDN link `https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.0.0-beta.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js`

Comment: Sorry not working, also not sure if we should be reverting back to the beta version. there is probably a different way this needs to be done.